# how we can convert categorical data in a column into numbered data

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

Lets take an example, suppose my table values are:

**subjects**

english

mathematics

science

english

science

how can i convert these string data into numbered data as shown in table below.

**subjects**

1

2

3

1

3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> df
      subjects
0      english
1  mathematics
2      science
3      english
4      science
```

you could use `pd.factorize`:

```
df['factor'] = pd.factorize(df['subjects'])[0]+1

>>> df
      subjects  factor
0      english       1
1  mathematics       2
2      science       3
3      english       1
4      science       3
```

or, if you simply want to replace the values in `subjects` rather than create a new column `factor`, do this:

```
df['subjects'] = pd.factorize(df['subjects'])[0]+1
```

Note that the `+1` is simply to get your exact output ranging from 1 to 3. Without it, you will still get valid categories, only ranging from 0 to 2.